# sql multiple concatenation in a string

Tags: string, t-sql, concatenation

I have a big problem that I don't understand.

I have this query in Tsql :

```
SET @sSQL = 'SELECT * 
  INTO '+@sTableValeursDefaut+' 
  FROM OPENQUERY(LINKSVR_LOCAL , '' SET FMTONLY OFF 
  EXEC [AIGP].[dbo].[rp_WEB_ValeursDefaut_Get] 
  '''''+'sds'+''''',
  '+ISNULL(CONVERT(VARCHAR, @fkIDProjet), 'NULL+')+',
  '+'123'+''')'

EXEC(@sSQL)
```

This work perfectly. But when I change the **'123'** for `CONVERT(VARCHAR, @fkIDCfgFormulaire)` and the **'sds'** to `@sNoUsager` the query don't work !

```
SET @sSQL = 'SELECT * 
  INTO '+@sTableValeursDefaut+' 
  FROM OPENQUERY(LINKSVR_LOCAL , '' SET FMTONLY OFF 
  EXEC [AIGP].[dbo].[rp_WEB_ValeursDefaut_Get] 
  '''''+@sNoUsager+''''',
  '+ISNULL(CONVERT(VARCHAR, @fkIDProjet), 'NULL+')+',
  '+CONVERT(VARCHAR, @fkIDCfgFormulaire)+''')'

EXEC(@sSQL)
```

What I am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without more information it's difficult to tell. Could be anything from the datatypes of the variables to the value of the variables you are passing...

We could do with some test data please.

It may also be that you have a '+' character in your literal I haven't tested it but `'NULL+'` should probably read `'NULL'`

Or it could be because in your `CONVERT(VARCHAR, @fkIDProjet)` you don't give a length to your varchar try something like this instead `CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), @fkIDProjet)`